# How to change the name of the descriptive statistics with the tbl_summary function in R?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I want to change the name of the descriptives statistics (Sum by Total, median by Médiane etc).

The code that i've tried is this one :

```
data %>%
tbl_summary(
by = year,
type = list(c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5") ~ 'continuous2'),
statistic = list(
  c("x1", "x2", "x3") ~ c(
    "{sum}",
    "{median} ({p25} - {p75})",
    "{mean} ({min} - {max})"
  ),
  c("x4", "x5") ~ c(
    "{median} ({p25}, {p75})",
    "{mean} ({min}, {max})"
  ),
  x6 ~ "{p}%"
)) %>%
modify_header(label = "**Variables**") %>%
as_gt() %>%
tab_header("Table 1") %>%
tab_options(
table.font.size = "small",
data_row.padding = gt::px(1)
)
```

The previsous code works the problem comes when i add this :

```
 add_stat_label(list(
          c("x1", "x2", "x3)")  ~ c(
      "Total",
      "Médiane (25% - 75%)",
      "Moyenne (Min - Max)"), 
      c("x4", "x5")~ c(
      "Médiane (25% - 75%)",
      "Moyenne (Min - Max)")))
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Can you please share a fully reproducible example? It makes it much easier for others to help if they can run your code to recreate the issue.

Comment: I have edited my question I hope is better